# Error on npm run build

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm, webpack

Error on npm run build. Updating the node-modules or clearing the cache didn't work. Updating the scripts even didn't work. Couldn't resolve the following error

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>           1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>           1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>           1 verbose cli   'run',
>           1 verbose cli   'build' ]
>           2 info using npm@6.0.1
>           3 info using node@v8.11.2
>           4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
>           5 info lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~prebuild: udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0
>           6 info lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~build: udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0
>           7 verbose lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
>           8 verbose lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~build: PATH: C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\Desktop\Angular-Udemy\seed-project\node_modules.bin;C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\Python\Scripts;C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\Python;C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\AppData\Roaming\npm;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
>           9 verbose lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~build: CWD: C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\Desktop\Angular-Udemy\seed-project
>           10 silly lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
>           10 silly lifecycle   'del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch' ]
>           11 silly lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
>           12 info lifecycle udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
>           13 verbose stack Error: udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 build: `del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch`
>           13 verbose stack Exit status 1
>           c
>           13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
>           13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
>           13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>           13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>           13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
>           13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
>           14 verbose pkgid udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0
>           15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\Desktop\Angular-Udemy\seed-project
>           16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
>           17 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
>           18 verbose node v8.11.2
>           19 verbose npm  v6.0.1
>           20 error code ELIFECYCLE
>           21 error errno 1
>           22 error udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 build: `del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch`
>           22 error Exit status 1
>           23 error Failed at the udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 build script.
>           23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>           24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Here, I upload the package.json

```
    {
  "name": "udemy-nodejs-angular2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'assets/app/**/*.js' 'assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.*'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "~1.15.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.14.0",
    "hbs": "~3.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.3",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "^2.0.1",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "del-cli": "^0.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: try to install latest version of nodejs and angular-cli

Comment: can you share with us package.json

Answer (score 3):

I've installed with ubuntu on your same package.json and it worked just fine.

I'm using node V8.11, npm 6.10;

It seems that you are using node 6.0 in your machine and node 8.0;

First, a good try is to update your npm to 6.10 and your node to a newer version, or just reinstall node. But it is more likely to be your user having no access to finish the build proccess as you can see in

```
`
    14 verbose pkgid udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0
    15 verbose cwd C:\Users\Bhargavii Nadendla\Desktop\Angular-Udemy\seed-project
    16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
    17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Bhargavii Nadendla\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
    18 verbose node v8.11.2
    19 verbose npm  v6.0.1
    20 error code ELIFECYCLE
    21 error errno 1
    22 error udemy-nodejs-angular2@1.0.0 build: `del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch`
    22 error Exit status 1
```

`

Whenever that happen i just run sudo on ubuntu and it is fixed. What are the permissions that your user have in the `project folder node_modules` and essentially in `"C:\\Users\\Bhargavii Nadendla\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"` ?

If it is not permission related, try out to install a newer version of node and point it out to C: removing it from AppData of windows, this can actually cause a access permission fail.